# Update only month and date of string in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update only the month and the day of a string. So example given: In my database i have a `DATETIME` column. Let's say that has the value `2018-01-08 00:00:00`. The user gives in another date which he would like to update. E.g. `2017-11-07 00:00:00`. I have a check on the code which descides if the date is different. So we'll skip that. I only want to update the month and the day of that string. So i don't want to update the time and year. The name of my `DATETIME` column is `upDatum` I've searched everywhere for this but there is no concrete answer. Here is what i have:

```
$query = "UPDATE twh_uren_prognose SET upUren = 
".$key['inputupuren'].", MONTH(upDatum) = ".$month.", DAY(upDatum) = 
".$day." WHERE upID = ".$key['inputupid'];
```

My question is: How can i only `UPDATE` the month and the day of a `DATETIME` MySQL column. I'm a little stuck. The Query which i'm talking about goes like this:

I hope this is kinda clear! Thanks!

Comment: And using what https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html has to offer, you should be able to compose your new date value from whatever parts you want.

Comment: @CBroe Am i asking for a tutorial on Prepared Statements? No, i am asking for help on my problem. So i don't know why i am getting downvoted?

Comment: You (also) asked whether anyone “had an idea” regarding your SQL injection vulnerability. _“I just need some help on the UPDATE query”_ - then tell us what specifically you need help with, and show us what you tried.

Comment: \o  I downvoted, so don't blame that on CBroe. Usually I comment as well, but since (s)he already was commenting similar things as I would, I didn't. The reasons: I think your question is poorly written, doesn't explain well what is going on (*"update is working, so I just need help on the update"*), and what error you get, if any. Also, you start rejecting comments and suggestions **IN BOLD CAPITAL** before they are even there. If you want to get help being a better programmer, please ask a better question. If you just want somebody to yell at until your problem is solved, hire somebody.

Comment: Updated my question!

Comment: To insert or update a DATETIME value in MySQL, you need to build the entire date and time value.  It is one value, you can't upgrade only the month.  So lets say the user gives you a new $month and a new $day, do: `$newdate = "$day-$month-$currentyear $currenthour:$currentmin:$currentsec";`  Could be simpler (ex $currenttime contains the entire time), only wanted to show you the idea.  The you update the value to $newdate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making a new date, using the day and month you entered in php and the year you allready had in mysql

```
$extraWhereTwee = ', MONTH(upDatum) = '.$month.', DAY(upDatum) = 
'.$day.'';
$query = "UPDATE twh_uren_prognose SET upUren = 
".$key['inputupuren'].", upDatum = STR_TO_DATE('".$day.",".$month.", YEAR(upDatum)','%d,%m,%Y') WHERE upID = ".$key['inputupid'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm gonna try this one

Comment: i see where you are heading, but i dont get the YEAR(upDatum) part. also when i run this code it does update the database, it gives no errors, but it updates every line to 30 00 -1...

Comment: The YEAR(upDatum), gets the actual year you have in the column upDatum, so you only change the day and month. Can you upload a "print" of your query?

Comment: It's still the same as asked in the question